# Chilli Source Android build on windows

Tags: java, android, c++, ant

I've tried building the CSEmptyTemplate project in eclipse for android but have run into a host of issues with it.

Looking at the documentation, it doesn't appear as if it should be this difficult.

Firstly, I've installed cygwin and installed the devel package to get make.exe and gcc compilers. I'm also using cygwin as part of the tool chain.

However, the error I keep getting is 'make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.'.

Any advice on fixing these issues would be appreciated.

edit: Found the make files. I was just an idiot last night when working on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any additional steps required to build Chilli Source for android on windows, just the simple steps listed on the website here: http://chilli-source.chilli-works.com/docs/?page_id=67

However setting up the Android Development Tools with the NDK can be a bit of a pain. Judging by the error your getting my gut feeling is that something isn't set up correctly there.

Chilli Source requires the latest versions of the SDK, NDK and ADT. Can you ensure you have:

- Android API level 21.
- The latest versions of the Built Tools, Platform Build Tools and Google Play Services.
- NDK revision 10c.

The latest ADT is also missing a couple of things that means it can't be used out of the box.
It doesn't come with the native dev tools which can be acquired by doing the following:

- Go to "Help" then "Install New Software..."
- Select "Android Developer Tools Update Site - https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse". You make have to edit it to instead point to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
- In Developer Tools select and install Android Native Development Tools.

It also doesn't come with ant. This isn't causing your issue, but it will cause issues later on, so get it following these steps:

- Go to "Help" then "Install New Software..."
- Select "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"
- In General Purpose Tools select and install Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment.

Now that you've got everything required, ensure that you've got it set up correctly:

- The correct version of the SDK selected the Android tab in preferences.
- The correct version of the NDK selected in the Android/NDK tab in preferences.
- Android 5.0 selected in the Android tab in Project Properties.

Finally, on windows you also need Cygwin. It's been a while since I've used it (I'm not a fan of cygwin so I do my Android development in a Ubuntu virtual machine) but only the "devel" package is needed iirc, so make sure you've at least got that.

Hopefully ensuring all of that is set up correctly will fix your problem!

Comment: That's done it! Looks like the ndk wasn't set up properly and I needed the android developer tools too. It might be worth updating the docs with this information. Reading this made it really easy to set up, before I wasn't quite sure what I was doing (too used to developing on macOS and not windows).

Comment: Unfortunately these issues are present in latest version of ADT on OSX and Linux too. I think it has pretty much been abandoned now that Android Studio is so close to release.